# GET request caching page response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I do not want the requested page to be cached by the browser. Would a post request fix this? Is there much downside to making a POST instead of a GET?

At the moment I am using like:

```
 $.get("/Client/JSON_GetInvoiceLines/" + ClientID, function (data) {
        //do stuff
    });
```

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting (1) the sensitive data returned by the server never to be stored by the client? If so, definitely use a POST request. Or (2) are you wanting only to ensure that fresh content is returned directly from the server with each request (rather than possibly cached content from some other node on the internet residing between the client and the origin server)? If so, then use a random query string as suggested by @market.

Comment: I just want fresh content. I didn't know about the "cache: false" property. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `cache` option in jQuery.

`$.ajax({
  url: '/Client/JSON_GetInvoiceLines/',
  type: 'GET',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
    // do stuff
  }
});`

It will append a random character string as a GET parameter to the end of your URL, so the browser won't cache it.

However, the ideal solution would be to disable caching on the server-side by setting headers, assuming you have control over the resource that you're requesting.

Comment: Yes, appending a random character string as part of the query string in a GET request is (unfortunately) the only sure way to break caches at all the intermediate servers that may lie between the client and the origin server. Theoretically the origin server can prevent this with headers, http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html but countless bad implementations exist. Hence, the use of random query string parameters, which continues today in current implementations of Yahoo Mail, and other industry-standard web applications.